# How to convert this to LINQ OR EF

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT EquipmentSerials.SerialNo,EquipmentSerials.IDNo,Equipments.Name,Equipments.TechOrder,Equipments.WorkUnitCode,Equipments.NationalStockNumber,Equipments.Manufacturer,Equipments.PartNumber,EquipmentSerials.ID,EquipmentSerials.EquipmentID,Discrepancy.Symbol
FROM EquipmentSerials
INNER JOIN Equipments ON (EquipmentSerials.EquipmentID = Equipments.ID)
INNER JOIN Discrepancy ON (EquipmentSerials.ID = Discrepancy.EquipmentSerialsID)
WHERE Discrepancy.Symbol='-'
```

Can anyone convert this to EF?

Thanks

Comment: Which are you using - EF **or** Linq-to-SQL ? Those are **two distinct** ORM tools by Microsoft - which one is it you're using??

Comment: The query is trivial and requires basic LINQ knowledge. What have you tried? What was the issue? Also when asking for EF query, at least provide the EF model involved.

Comment: im using EF, sorry

Comment: right now im stack with it, im using repository pattern, each table has already a Model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
var data= from EquipmentSerials in db.EquipmentSerials
      join Equipments in db.Discrepancy on EquipmentSerials.EquipmentID equals Equipments.ID
      join Discrepancy in db.Discrepancy on EquipmentSerials.ID equals Discrepancy.EquipmentSerialsID
      where Discrepancy.Symbol == "-"
      select new {
         EquipmentSerials.SerialNo,EquipmentSerials.IDNo,Equipments.Name,Equipments.TechOrder,Equipments.WorkUnitCode,Equipments.NationalStockNumber,Equipments.Manufacturer,Equipments.PartNumber,EquipmentSerials.ID,EquipmentSerials.EquipmentID,Discrepancy.Symbol};
```